# Error while showing map in an Android app of a user location derived from GPS

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm generating Google map by using the code below. What I am doing here is just get the longitude/lat from GPS. The output I get is just black screen with Google written below. The key and manifest(also layout) are correct as I tried the same code by hardcoding lon/lat and it worked. What might be the error?

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: are you getting an exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
and then this  Couldn't get connection factory client. This is repeating. No exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(strLocationProvider);` Try launching an app with location. I had this same issue, you are getting a dead location. If this doesn't work then try logging you results with logcat. Find out if the you are actually getting a location or not.

Comment: Are you asking me to use a hard coded location? That I already tried and it was working.

Comment: I am asking you to run an application that request a location like Google Maps. This will update the location to the current location. You are using `LastKnownLocation` which could mean that it is a dead location. Try to log the information is LogCat to view you results to ensure that you getting a location.

Comment: Can you give me a code snippet of how to do that? I am bit confused here.

Comment: @Hiccup - as you are not providing your own LocationListener in your app, you are relying on another app having previously obtained a GPS location. As you have set an ACCURACY_FINE criterion, then only a GPS fix, not a NETWORK one will prevent the location being null

Comment: `Log.i("lat", lat.ToString); Log.i("lon", lon.ToString);` This will display information in the LogCat under the tag `lat` and `lon` If both of the show as valid lat and lon data then we have to continue to look elsewhere. I am thinking it is null and you are not getting a location. Plus you are setting lat and lon even though you are checking for null. You need to place this all in the If statement for if it is null it won't be set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an NPE?  You are checking if location is null, but then -- even if it is -- you are using it's methods.